# Track scm changes

Tags: hudson

How do we track older builds which had a triggered because of check-in happened in Hudson,

For example I made build periodically a certain build and its fine, I want to look older builds only which had scm change.

Ex: Currently  I am in 200th build,I want to see older build say 76 if it had a change in SCM,i.e I should not click the 76th build console and see manually for any changes is there any way to determine by just seeing particular build number if that build had any change.

-Thanks
Pravin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to browse the changes associated with recent builds, there's a link on the project's sidebar to **Changes**. The URL should be `http://my-hudson-server/job/[job name]/changes`. It will show the list of builds that Hudson has a record of and the change summary for each build.

If you know the build number (and Hudson is keeping track of enough previous builds), then you can use the URL `http://my-hudson-server/job/[job name]/[build number]/changes`.

If you try to access a build that's too old and Hudson has gotten rid of, you'll get a 404 (not found) error.

Comment: Just tested it, Dave is right it only shows the build that have changes attached.